# eclipse memory analyzer showing garbage value

Tags: eclipse, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am using Eclipse Helios 3.6.2. I use it to do Android development using the ADT plugin. Recently I tried to check for memory leaks within an Android application that I have developed. For this I first got a hprof file from the DDMS view and then converted the hprof file to hpof using the hprof-conv tool provided in the Android sdk. By default the hprof file was not opening using MAT. 
Now when I try to open the hpof file using MAT, I see garbage values. Please refer to the picture:
[image]

What could be going wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening the data file as a text file in the text editor, not in the memory analyzer. This is almost certainly due to the misspelling of the file name -- should be `*.hprof`, not `*.hpof`. Close the file, rename it, and try reopening it!